# Bad Coloring in Mandelbrot set with C++ & OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, mandelbrot

I have the following Mandelbrot set code in C++ for use with opengl but the colours are not correct, these are the desired colors:
[image]

but I get this:
[image]

```
int vala = 600;
int valb = 600;
//render one frame
void Application::render(void)
{
    // Clear the window and the depth buffer
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //render grid

    Image img( vala, valb);
    double MinRe = -2.0;
    double MaxRe = 1.0;
    double MinIm = -1.2;
    double MaxIm = MinIm+(MaxRe-MinRe)*vala/valb;
    double Re_factor = (MaxRe-MinRe)/(vala-1);
    double Im_factor = (MaxIm-MinIm)/(valb-1);
    unsigned MaxIterations = 250;
    for(unsigned int y = 0; y < img.height; y++){ 
        double c_im = MaxIm - y*Im_factor;
        for(unsigned x=0; x< img.width; ++x){
            double c_re = MinRe + x*Re_factor;
            double Z_re = c_re, Z_im = c_im;
            bool isInside = true;
            for(unsigned n=0; n<MaxIterations; ++n){

                double Z_re2 = Z_re*Z_re, Z_im2 = Z_im*Z_im;
                if(Z_re2 + Z_im2 > 4)
                {
                    isInside = false;
                    break;
                }

                Z_im = 2*Z_re*Z_im + c_im;
                Z_re = Z_re2 - Z_im2 + c_re;


                double z = sqrt(Z_re*Z_re + Z_im*Z_im);
                int brightness = 256. *log(1.75 + n - log(log(z)));
                img.setPixel(x,y, Color(sin(time)*brightness, sin(time/2)*brightness, brightness));



            }


            }

        }


    img.scale( this->window_width, this->window_height );

    renderImage( &img );

    //swap between front buffer and back buffer
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(this->window);
}
```

Anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Other than `glClear (...)` there's not a single bit of GL code in here. I suspect the implementation of `Image` or `renderImage (...)` is to blame, but neither of them are shown. If you output directly to an image file instead of GL, does it change anything?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman It may not be much openGL code, but the rest of the program does include many lines of openGL code so the program itself must be 100% OpenGL supported.

Image and renderImage are not the problem, I guarantee it. The problem comes from the equation to print colors...

Comment: Oh, I see. I interpreted the question as though the image on the top was *also* generated using this code and that the miscolored image was the result of trying to display it in GL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the color inside the loop, which is different from any Mandelbrot code I have seen. It also sets the color for the same pixel many times, which is very inefficient. Another aspect of the logic problem is that you set `isInside`, but then never use it.

The way this is typically done is that you set the color after the loop terminated. If `isInside` is true, you set the color to black (or leave it untouched if the image was cleared to black). Otherwise you set the color. If you look at the [origin of the code you use](http://warp.povusers.org/Mandelbrot/), they suggest to determine the color in the "outside" case based on the number of iterations, which would be `n` in your case. The code you posted is using the value of `Z_re/Z_im` to determine the color.

Edit: Ok, your formula uses both `n` and `Z_re/Z_im`. In any case, unless you know exactly what forumula were used for the reference image, and you use the same, you can't expect exactly the same coloring. If you fix what I pointed out above, you should at least get black for the inside.